# Displaying assembly at CLion

Tags: assembly, mips, clion, jetbrains-ide, mips64

How can I see an assembly of C/C++ code at CLion IDE of JetBrains?
Can I configure to see specific assembly type (MIPS assembly)?

Comment: Assembly and disassembly support is on our 2017.1 roadmap (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CLION/Roadmap+for+CLion+2017.1). Please feel free to vote for the corresponding feature requests: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-1743 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-1748.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get the assembly output file using JetBrains CLion 2018.3?